# How do I get a random default value for a column in MySQL/Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a mysql table full of color values like "#EE3AA". And I have a model which has a color attribute, which is obligatory (should validate) but does not need to be entered by the user necessarily. If left empty by the user, I want it to be filled using a random value chosen from another table automatically, but not always the same value by default.

I thought, perhaps, I could do it using a migration, so it is like this:

```
... :default => "values of the color column of the Colors table".to_a.sample
```

My thinking may not be correct/legal in terms of Ruby. After seeing the :default option in the migrations files, I thought that the migration file is run every time a model is created. But reading Mikhail's comment, this may not be the case. But in any case, how I can get a random value from another table when none is supplied by the user?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. What do you mean by pulling data into a migration file?

Comment: In my opinion better to move this logic into model hook(before_save) it will be more maintainable and testable.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness of the question and late return. I edited the question.

Comment: Random default ... that reminds me of this: http://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrations are only run when you create a database or make changes to the structure of the database, not when saving a new record. Mikhail is correct in suggesting a `before_save` callback. You can do something like this in your model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_empty_color_to_random_value

  def set_empty_color_to_random_value
    self.color = Color.order("RANDOM()").first.color if self.color.empty?
  end
end
```

Note that `RANDOM()` works for PostgreSQL and SQLite, but not for MySQL. For MySQL you have to use `RAND()` instead.

Comment: +1 Great answer, in rails and model based. Nice job. Any thoughts on rspec tests using that?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant, thanks. I thought I saw a Railscast that talks about testing randoms, but I cannot find it. If I were to write a test for this I'd just check that when the color attribute is left empty it is not empty anymore after saving. I'd also test that the value it has after saving exists in the colors table. I would be interested in suggestions on testing wether something is *really* a random value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see the point. So even if I have a line in the migration file like this: "t.integer :cost, :default => (5..12).to_a.sample", it will not affect the newly created models and it should be in a before_save function.

Comment: @barerd: Yes, if you set the default randomly it will always be the same (yet randomly chosen) value. You are basically trying to do what is shown in the funny comic that arnep linked to. If you use a callback in your model, you will have a new random value for every record.

Comment: @Mischa: The above function worked well and encouraged, i tried rand() function to get random numeric values, but failed. Tried every post about rand in stackoverflow, but couldn't make create_model{(:rating => "5+rand(6)")} to get values between 5 and 10. Do you have any idea about this?