# How do I get saved database object in active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a column in my table which have a default value that I set during migration. When I save a record, that particular column's value is always nil in the returned object( `@payment = Payment.create(payment_params)`) but there is a value set in the database. I know that is how it should work but do you guys know how I can get the whole data after saving it???

## schema.rb

```
create_table "payments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "amount"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.uuid "uuid", default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, null: false
end
```

Comment: can you please add "payment_params" and what values you are passing or log of server ?

Comment: @Vishal, in `payment_params`, I have only `amount` because the other column value `uuid`  will have default value every time I save. The issue is that I want that `uuid` value returned after I persist data in the db. If I add `uuid` in `payment_params` then I will get the `uuid` value but since  the value for `uuid` is set by default, I didnt wanted to do that.

Comment: Please add your schema.rb file , code of controller in question

Comment: @Vishal, i have updated the question.

Comment: where your "gen_random_uuid" method is defined ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258253/how-do-i-get-a-random-default-value-for-a-column-in-mysql-rails

Comment: @Vishal, it's a built in method which is enabled after u enable `enable_extension 'pgcrypto'`

Comment: @iGian, I did it like that in one of my project but I was looking if there was other way to do it. Anyway, I guess I will do it like that. Thanks

Comment: @Raaz  do you get any error while creating record ? Please also try this ``default: "gen_random_uuid()" `, instead of `{ "gen_random_uuid()" },`

Comment: @Raaz Maybe this is a silly question but have you tried calling `@payment.reload` after it saves?